# Send info from EditText to IME

Tags: android, keyboard-layout, android-softkeyboard

I'm writing a language learning app, currently only German<->Russian.

There are several `EditTexts` where the user is supposed to enter text in one or the other language. As these languages use different alphabets, the app uses its own soft keyboard by implementing `InputMethodService` and providing both Latin and Cyrillic keyboard layout. It is known for each `EditText` field which language is expected.

What I would like is that, e.g., whenever an `EditText` field expecting Russian is in focus, the Cyrillic keyboard layout should be displayed. When selected, the `EditText` should pass some constant on to the IME, which the latter can use to decide whether to display in Latin or Cyrillic mode.

Ideally, one would simply specify some custom `InputType` for the `EditText` but that doesn't seem to be possible, does it? What is the correct approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea doesn't sound bad. IME's code check for the `InputType` in a switch block and the default keyboard layout is shown if the `InputType` didn't match.

You can also provide a logic in `onCreate()` method of your `Activity` to check which input method is active and with that info choose which `inputType` your `EditText` should have.

Comment: Hm, thanks. Thing is, I didn't know how to go about defining and using a custom InputType as I did not want to divert the standard InputType literals from their intended use. The communication from EditText to the IME wasn't clear to me. Now I'm using privateImeOption which works, but doesn't seem particularly beautiful to me ...